# Why in this C# .NET controller method do I have this signature?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am pretty new to C# .NET and I have the following doubt.

On a page on which I am working on I found the following link:

```
<a class="ui-btn-inline ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Groups", new { id = item.gruppoId })">Delete</a>
```

This link call a **Delete()** method on a **GroupsController** class.

Ok, this is this method:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
{
    .......................
    .......................
    .......................
    DO SOME STUFF
    .......................
    .......................
    .......................
    return View(model);
}
```

My doubt is related to the signature of this method: why is the parameter **int id = 0** ?

What does the **= 0** mean? To begin with I thought that this was a simple initialization and that it change the it value to 0 but using the debbugger I discovered that it don't change the id value. So what it exactly do?

Comment: [Named and Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd264739.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called an optional parameter. It means you can call the method with no argument, like this:

```
Delete();
```

If you do that, the value of the `id` parameter in the function will be `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You're right in saying that the `= 0` sets the value of the `id` parameter.

But it's important to note that it only does so **when you do not pass that parameter**.

Take for example:

```
public void SaySomething( var something = "Hello" )
{
    Console.WriteLine( something );
}

//...

SaySomething();
SaySomething("I am sleeping.");
```

The first call to the function does not pass a parameter. Therefore, the default value `"Hello"` is used to write to the console.

The second call already sets a value for the parameter, so it does not get overwritten by the default value you set up. `"I am sleeping."` will be printed in this case.

Comment: It's important to note that Code Analysis doesn't like this.  It'll tell you to overload the function with no parameter and call the one requiring the parameter from the parameterless function passing in the default value.

Comment: @Zach I haven't yet used Code Analysis. I'll take your word for it ;)

Comment: If you ever want Visual Studio to complain about how bad your code is, turn it on sometime.  :)